# Are all molecular structures symmetric?

Tags: molecules, symmetry

Are all molecular structure symmetric either in relation to a plane within itself or in relation to other molecules? Are there any completely asymmetrical structures when looking at molecular geometry? Are there any studies into the reason for symmetry?

Comment: There is no 'reason' for symmetry as such. Unless you mean symmetric *conformations* rather than arrangements?

Comment: Different molecules have different levels of symmetry - we put in lots of effort into finding out exactly how symmetrical molecules are because symmetry is the basis of lots of other things, most notably molecular orbitals. You can find out more about symmetry elements [here](http://symmetry.otterbein.edu/tutorial/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of notable types of structurally asymmetric molecules.

Firstly, those that are chiral due to different ligands attached to a central atom such as the improbable $\ce{CClFBrI}$ or 'bromo-chloro-fluoro-iodo-methane'. More generally, many molecules have chiral centers; sometimes multiple ones, like [inositol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inositol) which has 6 in a 6-carbon molecule.

Secondly, there are rarer structures where there are no chiral centers, but the whole thing is chiral. Usually this is because of steric restrictions that force it to be one shape or another. Helicene is a very nice example. Another might be a cage hydrocarbon in the shape of [this graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph) but I don't know if any exist.

Comment: are you saying  there are no structures that match Helicane? I am not referring to the position of ligands but the 3d structure specifically.

Comment: I'm saying that Helicane comes in two conformations that don't (readily?) interconvert and cannot be superimposed on each other.

Comment: Also, I apparently meant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicene not "Helicane" which turns out to be a character from Shakespeare!

Comment: I guess I am basically asking if there exist any chiral molecules without a matching enantiomer or if some symmetry is always seen when looking at all levels instead of just the individual molecule?

Comment: Ah, so theoretically every chiral molecule has a matching enantiomer - but we may not have observed them experimentally, or they might be unstable for some reason. I don't know of any chemically forbidden examples, although there are many *reactions* that force one enantiomer or another.

Comment: Notably, in biochemistry, you (mostly) get one chiral form : L-amino acids, for example. This is covered in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homochirality but there is a lot more research out there on this topic due to the question of why this happened in the origin of life.

Answer (score 5):

It is not quite clear what do you mean by "in relation to a plane within itself or in relation to other molecules", but I think the answer is *no*, not all molecules are symmetric. Many of them belong to what is known as $\mathrm{C}_1$ point group, or, in other words they are are totally asymmetric. For more information on molecular symmetry and point groups read [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_symmetry).